# Why does a $1 backreference work in a rewrite with no subgroups?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex, rewrite

Someone I'm working with committed a RewriteRule such as the following to SVN:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ebay.*$ /yii.php/$1 [L]
```

I warned him that it may not work because there is no subgroup in the match that would correspond to the $1 backreference. It does work, and I'm perplexed. I'm pretty sure what he intended was either of the following:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ebay.*$ /yii.php/$0 [L] # $0 is whole match
```

...or...

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ebay(.*)$ /yii.php/$1 [L] # $1 subgroup
```

Does Apache make an assumption about backreferences that I never knew about? Why does his RewriteRule (the top one) work?

Comment: From what I can tell URIs always start with `/` so `^admin` will never match anything.

Comment: There may be a configuration or circumstances in which that's true, but as far as I have ever seen, they do not begin with `/`. I just posted an answer to this particular issue.

Comment: In a _directory_ context (ie. inside a `<Directory>` container) then the slash prefix is omitted (the same as if used in `.htaccess`). However, if used in a _server_ (or _virtualhost_) context then the slash prefix is required (since it matches the full URL-path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the `$1` really *doesn't* do anything here. The following works just as well:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/ebay.*$ /yii.php [L]
```

(Notice no backreference at all in the rewrite part.)

This works because Yii is looking at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to figure out what the user intended. In fact Apache was just passing empty for the `$1` backreference as expected.

So no server fault here. :)

Comment: +1 correct, any "unfilled" back references will be blank if used.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).  The log might give you a hint about where that value is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm going to post an answer right now.